Reading an xlsx Excel file into a pandas dataframe with openpyxl generates value error
I have written a code using selenium to download an xlsx excel file from a website, rename it and then open it with openpyxl. however, trying to read the file into a pandas dataframe with openpyxl leads to an error.
The error is the following:
ValueError: Unable to read workbook: could not read stylesheet from ./ETF/test/test.xlsx.This is most probably because the workbook source files contain some invalid XML.Please see the exception for more details.

The file can be opened manually without any problems.
My code looks like this:
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import requests
from glob import glob  
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory":os.path.abspath("./ETF/test")}
# Define download path
op.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
# Google Chrome
PATH = r"./webdriver/chromedriver.exe"
#PATH = r"D:\Coding\Python\project1\webdriver\chromedriver.exe"
# Use Service to set the ChromeDriver path
service = Service(PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=op)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)


# Download and rename file if it doesn't exist
driver.get('https://www.amundietf.de/de/professionell') # Be aware in recent times, server is often down
driver.maximize_window()
# Wait for the "Professioneller Anleger" button to be present and clickable
profanleger_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Professioneller Anleger']")))
profanleger_button.click()
# Wait for the "Akzeptieren und fortfahren" button to be clickable and click it
akzept_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "confirmDisclaimer")))
akzept_button.click()
# Wait for the "Akzeptieren und fortfahren" button to be clickable and click it
cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "CookiesDisclaimerRibbonV1-AllOn")))
cookies_button.click()
time.sleep(2)

# Check whether file exists
if os.path.isfile('ETF/test/' + "Fondszusammensetzung_Amundi*"):
    print("File exists.")    
else:
    driver.get('https://www.amundietf.de/de/professionell/products/equity/amundi-index-msci-emerging-markets-ucits-etf-dr-d/lu1737652583')
    # Download file
    Komp_ETF_herunterladen_xpath = "//span[@class='pr-3 bold-text']"
    # Wait until the download button is clickable
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Komp_ETF_herunterladen_xpath)))
    dlbutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, Komp_ETF_herunterladen_xpath)
    dlbutton.click()
    time.sleep(20)  # Waiting is somehow necessary, otherwise renaming is not successful
    etf_path = './ETF/test/'
    f = glob(os.path.join(etf_path, "Fondszusammensetzung_Amundi*"))[0]
    os.rename(f, os.path.join(etf_path, 'test.xlsx'))

# Quit browser
driver.quit()
time.sleep(20)


df = pd.read_excel('./ETF/test/test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', skiprows=18, skipfooter=4, header=1, usecols="B:H")
df.to_csv('./ETF/test/test.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1', decimal=',')

I can open and edit the file in excel without any problems. I don't see any errors in the file.How can i make sure that i can read in the file as a dataframe, edit it and then export it as a csv file?

It's not beyond the realms of possibility that the Excel file does have some XML issue that Openpyxl doesn't like. Interacting with Openpyxl is not the same as Excel. Have you tried just opening the downloaded file separately with Openpyxl (just write some code to open the file with Openpyxl only). If that is a problem try opening the file in Excel and use SaveAs so the file is saved by Excel and try opening the resultant file again with Openpyxl.

I tried your code and it failed on clicking the Excel download buttons. Not sure if that's due to my location/region etc. However as it's not your issue I just went to the site you are opening and downloaded the two Excel files I could find on the site. One Excel file starts with 'Dokumentenliste...' and the other with 'Fondszusammensetzung...' Both files gave an XML error when trying to open directly in Openpyxl.

After opening and saving the files using Excel they opened in without error in Pandas/Openpyxl. Given you are unlikely to get the site owner to change their Excel file production, either you switch to Calamine as the engine if that works for you or after downloading the file(s) first open in Excel (using Xlwings or Win32com) use SaveAS from Excel and then you can use Pandas to open (with default Openpyxl). Of course opening and resaving may lose some Styling from the Sheet(s) depending on exactly what the issue is.

If its helpful this SO link is a piece of code that tries to open an Excel file with read_excel and if fails opens and saves using Xlwings then tries the open again using read_excel on the saved file

The exception is pretty clear: there workbook contains an invalid stylesheet according to the OOXML specification. It doesn't matter whether Excel can read the workbook or not.
